# Remove "Chapter" in header of the backmatter

Tags: header-footer

In my backmatter the header appears as `Chapter x: chapter-name`, where `x` is the number (or letter if I have an appendix) of the last chapter before the backmatter. How can I make the header in the backmatter to just show `chapter-name`? I already modified the `chaptermark` according to this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68241/36374) to not have the `Chapter 0` in the header of the frontmatter (Removing this does not affect the header in the backmatter). How can I adapt it to not have the `Chapter x` in the header?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
  \else
    \markboth{#1}{}%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 
\chapter{abstract}
some text

\mainmatter
\chapter{some chapter}
some text

\appendix
\chapter{some appendix}
some text

\backmatter
\chapter{some backmatter}
some text
\newpage
some text
\newpage
some text


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong conditional:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % as requested by fancyhdr's warning

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \if@mainmatter
    \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
  \else
    \markboth{#1}{}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 
\chapter{abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\chapter{some chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\appendix
\chapter{some appendix}
\lipsum[1-20]

\backmatter
\chapter{some backmatter}
\lipsum[1-20]


\end{document}
```

In the front and back matter the conditional `\if@mainmatter` is set to false.

Comment: Thanks. What are the `makeatletter` and the `makeatother` for?

Comment: I found the answer here: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is defining `\chaptermark` in a different way depending on whether you are in the "front", "main" or "back"-matter part of the document you can modify the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` so they change it for you as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\frontmatter}{
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{#1}{}%
    }    
}
\g@addto@macro{\mainmatter}{
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
    }    
}
\g@addto@macro{\backmatter}{
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{#1}{}%
    }    
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 
\chapter{abstract}
some text

\mainmatter
\chapter{some chapter}
some text

\appendix
\chapter{some appendix}
some text

\backmatter
\chapter{some backmatter}
some text
\newpage
some text
\newpage
some text


\end{document}
```

The `\g@addto@macro` macro appends some code to the definition of a macro; I use it here to add the corresponding redefinition of `\chaptermark` to each of them.