# Different header styles in Chapters with if@mainmatter

Tags: header-footer

I have a problem with the book,twoside documentclass and the headings in the respective second chapterpages.

In `\frontmatter` I use `Abstract` and `Acknowledgements`. In the `\mainmatter` I use `Contents`, `Introduction`, ...

Now I want to set the header for the frontmatter for example without the chapternumber `\thechapter` and the header in the mainmatter with the chapternumber.

Is there a way to do it like this?

I tried

```
\if@mainmatter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\textsc{\thechapter\ #1}}{}}  
\else
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\textsc{#1}}{}}
\fi
```

But it always displays the else branch.

Here is a MWE to show my problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\if@mainmatter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\textsc{\thechapter\ #1}}{}}%
\else
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\textsc{#1}}{}}%
\fi

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
\blindtext[4]
\chapter{Achknowledgements}
\blindtext[10]

\mainmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[15]

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `\if@mainmatter` inside the redefinition: `\makeatletter \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\if@mainmatter ...\else ...\fi} \makeatother`. Note that this does not affect the header entry of the table of contents.

Comment: yeah forgot `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` :( now it works damn

Comment: this is a similar question (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146106/remove-chapter-in-header-of-the-backmatter?rq=1

Comment: Maybe you can also search how to get »CONTENTS« in the page header with `\scshape` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the tableofcontents style I found in the book.cls the \newcommand\tableofcontents... which i reconfigured with: `\renewcommand`:

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%  
  \if@twocolumn  
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn  
  \else  
    \@restonecolfalse  
  \fi  

  \chapter*{\contentsname  
  \@mkboth{%  
  \scshape{\contentsname}}{\scshape{\contentsname}}}%  
  \@starttoc{toc}%  
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi  
}
```

this will change the CONTENTS style in the header. Equivalent you can also change the listoffigures and listoftables.